# Вопрос по синхронизации потоков на Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, синхронизация

У меня есть класс Res, содержащий синхронизированный метод A и несинхронизированный метод B. В другом классе я создаю экземпляр класса Res и два потока: первому потоку в качестве задачи назначаю выполнение синхронизированного метода A для экземпляра класса Res, а второму потоку назначаю выполнение несинхронизированного метода B для того же экземпляра класса Res. Из литературы я понял, что если синхронизированный метод получает управление, вызывающий поток активирует монитор, который блокирует объект для других потоков, то есть в моем примере сначала должен полностью отработать метод A, а только потом метод B. Однако я проверил и получается, что метод B почему то работает параллельно с методом A. Если я делаю метод B тоже синхронизированным, то эта параллельность пропадает. Получается, что если в одном потоке для объекта вызвался синхронизированный метод, то в другом потоке для этого же объекта может параллельно выполняться несинхронизированный метод? То есть блокируется возможность исполнения для объекта из другого потока только синхронизированных методов, а несинхронизированные методы могут выполняться?

```
public class Res {
    int number = 0;
    public synchronized void A(){
        for (int i = 0; i<10000; i++) {
            number += 1;
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }

    public void B(){
        for (int i = 0; i <10000; i++)
        number-=1;
        }
    }

public class Threads {

    Res commonRes = new Res();
    public void startThreads(){
        new Thread(()->commonRes.A()).start();
        new Thread(()-> commonRes.B()).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Код добавьте ,если есть возможность, проще будет ориентироваться

Comment: "вызывающий поток активирует монитор, который блокирует объект для других потоков" если они вызывают синхронизированные методы того же объекта.

Answer (score 1):

Несинхронизированным методам монитор не нужен (если конечно внутри этого метода нет захвата монитора через synchronized(...)). Когда Вы пишете нестатические синхронизированные методы, то они перед выполнением захватывают монитор текущего экземпляра. Именно, так сказать, не текущий экземпляр - а его монитор. Поэтому другие несинхронизированные нестатические методы могут работать спокойно из любого потока - им монитор не нужен. В случае статических синхронизированных методов будет захват монитора уже не экземпляра класса, а у самого класса. В больших приложениях если Вы хотите, чтобы монитор захватывался только вашим кодом, нужно создавать специальный не доступный другому коду объект, монитор которого ваши потоки будут захватывать.